# Why sc.next() is used in catch block?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, try-catch

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                long n=sc.nextLong();
                if((n>=(-128))&&(n<=127))
                System.out.println(n+" can be fitted in:\n* byte\n* short\n* int\n* long");
                else if(n>=(-32768)&&n<=32767)
                System.out.println(n+" can be fitted in:\n* short\n* int\n* long");
                else if(n>=(-Math.pow(2,31))&&n<=(Math.pow(2,31)-1))
                System.out.println(n+" can be fitted in:\n* int\n* long");
                else if(n>=(-Math.pow(2,63))&&n<=(Math.pow(2,63)-1))
                System.out.println(n+" can be fitted in:\n* long");
            }
            catch(Exception obj)
            {
                System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why `sc.next()` is used in the catch block System.out.println line of code?

Comment: To move past the token that gave an error.

Comment: ... and also (in this case) to show the user the data that couldn't be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

In here `sc.next()`, The `next()` method in java is present in the Scanner class and is used to get the input from the user.  This method can read the input only until a space(” “) is encountered. In other words, **it finds and returns the next complete token from the scanner.**

if we think we didn't use this `sc.next()` and just only the   `System.out.println(" can't be fitted anywhere.");` what happen is when the exception is catch it will print the output until one of your if block stratifies. As an example lets input `4lk` number with string it will output

```
 can't be fitted anywhere.
 can't be fitted anywhere.
 can't be fitted anywhere.
```

three times, but using the `sc.next()` we can avoid that because it will look for another input.